# Users and Roles for a Post in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have a number of users who have different roles in relation to a numbers of posts. These roles are `owner`, `editor`, `viewer`, `none`. Each user may only have **one** role for a post. I have represented this as a has many through relationship in rails as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :posts, :through => :roles
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :users, through => :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :role
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :posts
end
```

Where the role attribute is used to indicate which type of role the user has on the post.
When setting a new role I cannot simply use the `<<` operator as it wont set the `role` attribute. What is the preferred way of handling this situation? How can I enforce that there is only one role per user / post combination and enforce this in my `Role` creation logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in the creation of roles for the User , if he already has a role assigned in which case you can skip assigning this role.

```
unless user.roles.present?
  user.roles.create
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to make sure that no user will have more than one role for a certain post. If this is what you want to achieve then you just need to add uniquness validation to your `Role` mode

`validates :user_id, uniqueness: {scope: :post_id, message: 'User can have one role per post'}`

this will ensure that the combination of `user_id` and `post_id` will be unique, you can see more on rails guide on [validation with scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.htm).